# building my own lc meter - multi point gnd

Tags: grounding

I'm building my own lc meter using the attached schematic. What I don't understand is why there is more than one path to gnd? Does it not eventually get connected to the same point?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one connection to GND, either on the negative side of the battery or I am guessing through the power supply pins on the bottom of P2A.  Electrons will flow from every chip back to that one GND connection through its own unique path. There is nothing explicit on the schematic about how to connect the various GND triangles (this is done in layout), but the layout will have huge implications for how well the circuit functions.

Since this is a mixed analog/digital board, the biggest source of noise to eliminate is the digital noise polluting the analog return path.

Comment: you were saying it's bad practise to mix digital with analogue how do I isolate them from each other?

Comment: There is a lot written on good grounding technique.  As a start for your schepatic, keep the LC circuitry on the left physically distant from the digital circuitry on the right.  Use analog ground and digital ground planes.  Connect these ground planes at a single point close to the power supply.  I would also consider connecting P2A and P2B (1-1, 2-2,...) on an outer layer so that the connections can be broken (traces cut) but you don't need to install a jumper on the analog signals which may affect performance.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by JonnyBoats, I think this makes the schematic more readable. Imagine a huge schematic and only *one* GND point. Now for each component (there can be really a lot) connected to GND you would need to follow a thin line, just like in a maze... That's why I think it is common practice to do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand your confusion. You see lots of downward pointing triangles, like on the left of the battery (B1).

Yes, these are all connected together and are at chassis ground. This is just a form of shorthand when drawing schematics. Perhaps it stems from the old days of tube radios when components were mounted on a metal chassis rather than using printed circuit boards. Back then one would simply attach ground lugs, perhaps one at every tube socket, to the chassis and connect the wires to those ground lugs. The chassis itself served as the "wiring" to connect together the various ground points.